# build failed when push notification plug in added to project on mac

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using PhoneGap to build applications.
Application runs properly on emulator but when push notification plug in is added to project it gives build errors.
I searched this issue...initially it was found to be a common issue to many people...tried all solutions...but still the same build errors.

here is the plug in

```
sudo cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
```

one of the solution said try out with 1.2.3 version of push notification i.e

```
sudo cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push@1.2.3
```

There were no errors using this version but then it is older version want a solution with the latest version.
The latest is working on windows machine but not on MAC.

Here is the detailed error when used latest version

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/bunty/Library/android-sdk-macosx
 JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
> Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v13:23+.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v13/maven-metadata.xml
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v13/
 Required by:
     :android:unspecified
> Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
 Required by:
     :android:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 37.885 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command:     /Users/bunty/Documents/ParsianaApp/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/bunty/Documents/ParsianaApp/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [install guide](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md)

> You will need to ensure that you have installed the following items
>   through the Android SDK Manager:
>
> ```
> Android Support Library version 23 or greater
> Android Support Repository version 20 or greater
> Google Play Services version 27 or greater
> Google Repository version 22 or greater
> ```

You can do it manually or using this command:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter "extra"
```

Comment: got this solution already...anyways thanks...manual update worked for me 
:-)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use sudo for installing. It causes permissions issues.

Comment: if sudo is not used it gives the following error...
[Error Link](http://pastebin.com/tQApLY7C)

Comment: Looks like you have installed cordova with su also. This probably is the problem...

Comment: I reinstalled for this issue...while installing also it asked me to install with sudo...